# Direction with Multiple Stops - Google Map v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Assume that we understand how directionservice on Google Map v3 works and I got it populated on google map.

Let's say I have:

Start: Chicago

Waypoints: 1. LAX, 2. California, 3. New York

End: Michigan

If you plot this using the direction service and waypts, it won't plot it in the order above.

It'll plot:
1. Chicago
2. California
3. LAX
4. New York
5. Michigan

I think it somehow calculates the closest route basic on Start and End.

Is there a way that I can go about plotting in the order searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe its just a case of setting optimizeWaypoints:false in the request object

See the docs -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest

> If set to true, the DirectionService will attempt to re-order the
>   supplied intermediate waypoints to minimize overall cost of the route.
>   If waypoints are optimized, inspect DirectionsRoute.waypoint_order in
>   the response to determine the new ordering.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I missed. XD